# Using the DetailView how do I get the selected row value on the DetailViewController.m file?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, uitableview

I trying to save my plist after a simple detail change.

Here's the line that I need fixed.

```
[plist replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:nameDictionary];
```

I need to replace the 0 with a variable that gets the row that was selected.  Remember, I'm using the codebase from the tutorial above.

something like indexPath.row would be great but I can't get it to work.

My array is no longer accessible on the detail view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way...
Create a NSInterger object in DetailsView.lets say mySelectedIndex

inside **RootViewControlle** didSelectRowAtIndexPath ..you can access mySelectedIndex

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

dvController.mySelectedIndex = indexPath.row;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

**inside DetailsView**

```
[plist replaceObjectAtIndex:mySelectedIndex withObject:nameDictionary];
```

Second..
Singleton Variable to store the data and access it anywhere in the App.

Third..
Use NSUSerDefaults..

Comment: Just remember you'd have to pass an NSInteger on the .h otherwise with a string you'd need to do:    int iSelectedIndex = [mySelectedIndex intValue];<br>[plist replaceObjectAtIndex:iSelectedIndex withObject:nameDictionary];